# Accessing object outside function in cocos2d

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am new to javascript and I am trying to create game via cocos2d js, I am trying to access object outside of function

```
var self = this;
var url = "image/background";

cc.loader.loadRes(url, cc.SpriteFrame, function (err, spriteFrame) {
var node = new cc.Node("background");
var sprite = node.addComponent(cc.Sprite);
sprite.spriteFrame = spriteFrame;
self.node.addChild(node);
 self.custombg = node;
 console.log(self.custombg); //works
});

console.log(self.custombg); //not works
```

Why cant I access `self.custombg` outside of function even though I declared it outside of function. Instead fixing code , some one help me understand how it works and what should I learn to master this ,Like oop in javascrippt , or what should I google to learn all the concept of cocos2d js.

Comment: Its async. Your last line executes before execution of your callback function.

Comment: how to call function after it completes

Comment: you can do it inside your callback function

Comment: thank you got it with 3rd parameter